# Pegar somente os valores que são diferentes na consulta

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Fiz uma consulta que traz os valores de credito e débito, porém necessito trazer somente os valores que são diferentes destes dois campos. No momento eu não sei porque ele está trazendo todos. Vejam na imagem: OBS É EM SQL SERVER

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código sql:

```
  declare @data date='2018-05-21'
  select * from (select sum (ContabLancValor) as debito,ContabLancNumCtrl, 
  CAST(ContabLancHistComp AS varchar(max)) as NomeCliente  from 
  CONTAB_LANCAMENTO 
  where ContabLancData >=@data
  and ContabLancData <=@data
  and ContabLancCtaCred is not null
  and EmpCod='01.02'
  group by CAST(ContabLancHistComp AS varchar(max)), ContabLancNumCtrl)debito
  inner join(

  select sum (ContabLancValor) as credito,ContabLancNumCtrl from 
  CONTAB_LANCAMENTO 
  where ContabLancData >=@data
  and ContabLancData <=@data
  and ContabLancCtaDeb is not null
  and EmpCod='01.02'
  group by CAST(ContabLancHistComp AS varchar(max)), ContabLancNumCtrl) credito 
  on credito.ContabLancNumCtrl=debito.ContabLancNumCtrl
  where debito.debito<>credito.credito
```

Comment: Se precisa executar no `sql-server`, edite a pergunta e remova os outros sgbd's para evitar dúvidas

Comment: `select A.* from CONTAB_LANCAMENTO A inner join CONTAB_LANCAMENTO B on B.ID = A.ID and A.Valor != B.Valor`, com o tempo elaboro uma resposta completa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felipe, se entendi corretamente o que necessita é saber quais lançamentos possuem divergência entre a somatória de débitos e de créditos. Se for esse o caso, avalie se o código abaixo te atende.

```
-- código #1 v2
;
with agrupaLanc as (
SELECT ContabLancNumCtrl, 
       sum(case when ContabLancCtaCred is not null then ContabLancValor else 0 end) as soma_debito,
       sum(case when ContabLancCtaDeb is not null then ContabLancValor else 0 end) as soma_credito
  from CONTAB_LANCAMENTO
  where ContabLancData = @data
        and EmpCod='01.02'
  group by ContabLancNumCtrl
)
SELECT A.ContabLancNumCtrl, A.soma_debito, A.soma_credito,
       L.ContabLancValor, L.ContabLancHistComp,
       L.ContabLancCtaCred, L.ContabLancCtaDeb
  from agrupaLanc as A
       inner join CONTAB_LANCAMENTO as L on L.ContabLancNumCtrl = A.ContabLancNumCtrl
  where A.soma_debito <> A.soma_credito;
```

Comment: O meu código traz certo, tipo ele traz aqueles que são diferentes. Eu precisava trazer daqueles do total o nome de cada um. Tipo são 3 registros que somam aquele total e eu necessitava pegar eles, junto com o total

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro nesse seu codigo: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Felipe, a mensagem de erro acima só ocorre se o comando anterior ao WITH não foi encerrado com ";".  Na dúvida, acrescente o caractere ";" antes de WITH. Alterei o código #1 com esta sugestão.